# Is there an extension for visual studio 2019 that highlights assembler syntax for NASM?

Tags: visual-studio, x86, visual-studio-2019, nasm, visual-studio-extensions

I was thinking about switching to using VS2019 to develop low level assembly stuff in NASM but I couldn't find any extensions for specifically NASM, I could only find one called AsmDude but that's for MASM, I looked everywhere and couldn't find anything, the only ones I found were for VSCode but I personally prefer VS2019 to that, Does anyone know of a NASM syntax highlighting extension for VS2019?

Comment: I also don’t find a suitable extension, maybe it indicates that VS 2019 is not the most suitable IDE to develop NASM? Perhaps you should try VS Code.

Comment: Have you tried [AsmDude](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Henk-JanLebbink.AsmDude) extension? It might have some support.